# Java ME plud-in issue for Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, java-me, eclipse-mars

I had to switch between Kepler and Mars because of Java ME. (I wasn't able to install Java ME plugin on Kepler). Now I can't create new Java ME project, an error appears:

The selected wizard could not be started.

```
Plug-in org.eclipse.mtj.ui was unable to load class org.eclipse.mtj.internal.ui.wizards.midlet.NewMidletWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.mtj.ui (599).
```

The menu Window -> Preferences -> Java ME also doesn't work. It shows "An error has occurred when creating this preference page." And error appears:

```
Unable to create the selected preference page.
    An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.mtj.ui (599).
```

And the log file contains:

```
    !SESSION 2015-09-27 21:25:19.484 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=4.5.0.I20150603-2000
    java.version=1.8.0_60
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data d:\workspace -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

    This is a continuation of log file D:\workspace\.metadata\.bak_0.log
    Created Time: 2015-09-27 21:28:00.484

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2015-09-27 21:28:00.484
    !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/mtj/internal/core/util/Utils
        at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.util.MTJBuildPropertiesResourceListener.filterResourceDeltas(MTJBuildPropertiesResourceListener.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.util.MTJBuildPropertiesResourceListener.resourceChanged(MTJBuildPropertiesResourceListener.java:91)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:373)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1470)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2250)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$NotifyJob.run(NotificationManager.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 4 2 2015-09-27 21:28:00.500
    !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.core.resources".
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/mtj/internal/core/util/ClasspathChangeMonitor$ClassPathVisitor
        at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.util.ClasspathChangeMonitor.resourceChanged(ClasspathChangeMonitor.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:299)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:289)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:152)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:373)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1470)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2250)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$NotifyJob.run(NotificationManager.java:43)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.core 4 2 2015-09-27 21:28:00.781
    !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jdt.core".
    !STACK 1
    org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in org.eclipse.mtj.core was unable to load class org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.build.MTJCompilationParticipant.
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:176)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$CompilationParticipants$1.run(JavaModelManager.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelManager$CompilationParticipants.getCompilationParticipants(JavaModelManager.java:339)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.initializeBuilder(JavaBuilder.java:589)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.builder.JavaBuilder.build(JavaBuilder.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:734)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:205)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$1.run(BuildManager.java:300)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:303)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuildLoop(BuildManager.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:144)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.mtj.core (587).
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.sources.SingleSourcePackage.loadClass(SingleSourcePackage.java:36)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:398)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:755)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:706)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:531)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:324)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:327)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:402)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:573)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin$1.run(WorkbenchPlugin.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceNode.createPage(WorkbenchPreferenceNode.java:48)
        at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.createPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1300)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.createPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:355)
        at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog.showPage(PreferenceDialog.java:1187)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.FilteredPreferenceDialog.showPage(FilteredPreferenceDialog.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9$1.run(PreferenceDialog.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
        at org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceDialog$9.selectionChanged(PreferenceDialog.java:670)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$3.run(StructuredViewer.java:877)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:173)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.firePostSelectionChanged(StructuredViewer.java:874)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handlePostSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1243)
        at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$5.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1269)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.firePostSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$5(OpenStrategy.java:259)
        at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1$2.run(OpenStrategy.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4155)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3772)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:827)
        at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:803)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.open(WorkbenchPreferenceDialog.java:211)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.OpenPreferencesAction.run(OpenPreferencesAction.java:63)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:473)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:595)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:420)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4180)
        at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3769)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
        at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
    Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.mtj.core.MTJCore.start() of bundle org.eclipse.mtj.core.
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:792)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:721)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:941)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:318)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:571)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.util.SecureAction.start(SecureAction.java:454)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.hooks.EclipseLazyStarter.postFindLocalClass(EclipseLazyStarter.java:107)
        ... 93 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/osgi/framework/debug/FrameworkDebugOptions
        at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.hooks.Debug.(Debug.java:31)
        at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.hook.sourceMapper.SourceMapperAccess.setSourceMapper(SourceMapperAccess.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.mtj.core.MTJCore.start(MTJCore.java:490)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:771)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:764)
        ... 100 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.osgi.framework.debug.FrameworkDebugOptions cannot be found by org.eclipse.mtj.core.hooks_1.0.0.201101310801
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 107 more
```

If someone knows how to fix this issue, I will be so glad.
Thanks!

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message

Comment: Do you really need to use Eclipse with MTJ? If not, you should move to Netbeans.

Comment: I prefer to work with Eclipse. I updated the content with my log file.